# DHCP and hosting with MAMP on a network

Tags: networking, dhcp, mamp

Im hosting a small DB app on my computer, my ip is attributed with DHCP and so Im not too sure on how to provide aces to this page that im hosting with MAMP on  a Mac, all computers on the network are Macs.

Is it possible that instead of providing my users with

http://192.168.1.64:8888/myapp

use:

(htpp:)//My_Computer_Name_on_the_Network:8888/myapp

Thank you.

PS. never mind the funny address below, im limited to posting only one url :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't Macs provide the mDNS service for local intranet lookups?  If your computer's name is `hostname`, mDNS should provide `hostname.local` to be resolvable from other mDNS-enabled computers on the network.  So your URL would become:

`http://hostname.local:8888/myapp`

Test this from the terminal with `ping hostname.local` (from a computer other than the one hosting your DB).